# How do I record audio on Android and change the pitch?

Tags: java, android, audio, attributes

I am trying to learn Android Development and I was wondering how I can capture audio from a microphone and then change the voice in the audio so that it sounds thicker or sharper etc. 
In short: How do I record and change the parameters of a sound? (In java, of course)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm actually working on an [android app that involves audio](https://github.com/CuiBono/cuibono_android/blob/master/src/org/cuiBono/CuiBono.java). Recording the audio is the easy part, and you can mostly copy my code for that. Writing an audio filter is a much harder task, and requires knowledge of digital signal processing and the [Fast Fourier Transform (FFT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)

You could start by reading about [audio processing in java here.](http://www.jsresources.org/faq_audio.html#sec_processing)

Meanwhile, here's the code to record audio on android:

```
public String record() {

                // please note: the emulator only supports 8 khz sampling.
                // so in test mode, you need to change this to
                //int frequency = 8000;

                int frequency = 11025;

                int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
                int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                .getAbsolutePath() + "/reverseme.pcm");

                // Delete any previous recording.
                if (file.exists())
                        file.delete();

                // Create the new file.
                try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create "
                                        + file.toString());
                }

                try {
                        // Create a DataOuputStream to write the audio data into the saved
                        // file.
                        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
                        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

                        // Create a new AudioRecord object to record the audio.
                        int bufferSize = 2 * AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency,
                                        channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
                        AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(
                                        MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, frequency,
                                        channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, bufferSize);

                        short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];
                        audioRecord.startRecording();

                        Log.e(tag, "Recording started");

                        long start = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                        long end = start + 15000;
                        while (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() < end) {
                                int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                                for (int i = 0; i < bufferReadResult; i++)

                                        if (ByteOrder.nativeOrder().equals(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)) {
                                                dos.writeShort( EndianUtils.swapShort(buffer[i]));                                                
                                        } else {
                                                dos.writeShort( buffer[i] );                                                                
                                        }
                        }

                        Log.e(tag, "Recording stopped");

                        audioRecord.stop();
                        bos.flush();
                        dos.close();
                        isRecording = false;
                        return file.getAbsolutePath();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(tag, "Recording Failed:" + e.getMessage());
                        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create " + e.getMessage());

                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android SoundPool to chnage the pitch of audio file check answers of [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939411/android-audio-change-pitch) question.

And to record audio when someone speaks near MIC check this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665890/how-to-detect-when-there-is-some-speech-near-mic-in-android).