# How to change the value of an audio file's Pitch

Tags: android, audio, media-player, media, pitch-shifting

I'm developing an app in Android to change the all recorded audio files by men voice to the women voice.

I found a solution to change the Pitch value of an audio file by PlaybackParams in MediaPlayer.
Here's my code for changing Pitch value:

```
mediaPlayer =new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(ur);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    PlaybackParams params = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        params = new PlaybackParams();
        try {
            params.setPitch(Float.parseFloat(1.6f));
        }catch (Exception e){
            params.setPitch(1.6f)
        }
        mediaPlayer.setPlaybackParams(params);
    }
```

It works well, but the problem is that it works only on Android above version 5.
Does anyone know another solution for that?

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/13046201/1735100