# Android - How to convert music frequency from 440Hz to 432Hz

Tags: android, frequency

I want to convert a music file that frequency from 440Hz to 432Hz. Please help me on it, i don't know use any library or algorithm in order to complete it...

Comment: music sampled at 440hz is going to sound pretty crappy. unless it's (maybe) a skrillex tune, in which case even sampling at 0.0000000000001hz would be overkill.

Comment: 432 Hz is 8 Hz below the standard concert pitch. Thus, the question is how to reduce the pitch of music by some 2%. Sounds like a reasonable question to me!

Comment: There is a related question with some comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251997/android-how-to-shift-pitch-of-output-sound-realtime The term to ask Google for is "pitch shifting"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get yourself setup and familiar with the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).

After that you can try using some [source from Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/source), or the [libsoxr](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Libsoxr) library itself.

:)

Comment: unfortunately I'm not familiar with NDK

Comment: @vodailuong Well, this looks like an excellent opportunity to familiarize yourself with it!

Comment: Or my script with ffmpeg: https://gist.github.com/ManuelTS/c232a70e081558dfcd6c797f991009df