# How to do Ramp Slow Mo in android?

Tags: android, video, android-2.2-froyo, android-video-player, android-audiomanager

Update:

**Question in Short:**

1. How to do **Audio** **Time Stretching** and **Pitch shifting** in Android?
2. How to **slow** mo the **video**?

**Question in detail:**

**What am I trying to do?**

I am trying to do **ramp slow mo** in a video file along with the audio and have to save the processed videos.

---

What is **ramp slow mo** or what i want to do ?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJ3_xMGzauk

---

The slow mo **effect** has to be taken place in the form of English letter **"U"**.

**Normal Slow Mo** : " |__| "(Linear - like slowing down the video to 2x or 4x)

**Ramp Slow Mo :** "  U  "  (Parabolic)

I have already done this app for IOS devices successfully.

---

**How i achieved ramp slow mo for IOS?**

Separated audio and video.

For video,I did dynamic time stretching to achieve parabolic effect.

```
for(i=0;i=around 10 intervals;i++)
{
  do time stretching
}
```

For Audio, along with time stretch, i also did pitch shifting as in the you tube link.

```
for(i=0;i=around 10 intervals;i++)
{
  do time stretching 
  do Pitch shifting 
}
```

---

**Questions**:

1. How to do this effect in Andorid? Are there **default API's available** in **Android SDK** to do ramp slow mo(**Audio/Video** Time Stretching + **Audio** Pitch shifting)?
2. As part of third party packages,for IOS, i used **Dirac** to do Audio Time Stretching and Pitch shifting. But unfortunately DIRAC is not available for android platforms.

Comment: Any input from experts?

Comment: What is i , in the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot speak about the best solution for video (short of implementing your own custom view with the special requirements you've provided), but I have some input on audio playback. Android supports a sample playback class that allows playback rate control:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

It's one thing to change the sample playback rate; you wanted to perform what sounds like independent time stretch and pitch shift. This is the domain of an FFT based class of algorithms called Phase Vocoders. With respect to audio, I would start by looking at libraries in Java for such effects. If you want to roll your own, this answer should get you off to a good start:

[Android: How to shift pitch of output sound (realtime)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251997/android-how-to-shift-pitch-of-output-sound-realtime)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I am going to try out what ever you provided. How to do slow mo for video ?